# Creating popup list and selecting from the list

Tags: android, popupmenu

I want to make a popup list like above in that list there will be different distances and when i click on a distance in that distance's description will be shown from the following list. please help 
atleast tell how to make popup list. For Android
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html). Its very easy to use. If you're only using a specific set of values for the drop down list you can use string array resource as the source of data for the Spinner. Define in XML under the values directory an array like this. Put as many items in as you need for the Spinners drop down list.

```
<string-array name="distances">
    <item>1 Mile</item>
    <item>2 Miles</item>
</string-array>
```

In a layout file define a Spinner widget

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDistances"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then in whatever activity you use that layout in:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDistances);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.distances, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Don't forget to define an event listener for the spinner so the program can do something when a user selects something on the Spinner.

EDIT:
To do something when an item is selected from the spinner you need to override OnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected() and set the Spinner to use that listener with Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(). You can do this by making your class implement OnItemSelectedListener and implementing the required methods or something like:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)         
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

    @Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have created spinner it works fine. All i want to do is when i select an item from spinner say i have selected 1.1mile then a list item like in figure above 1.1mile away is at top of the list . THat I want to do . How will I do that?????

Comment: I mean if 1Mile is selected from spinner then in listView all the items will be for 1Mile. 2Mile,5Mile etc. will not be shown

Comment: If you want to repopulate the ListView when a spinner item is selected you need to assign a OnItemSelectedListener to the spinner and perform your changes on the list on onItemSelected.

Comment: can you tell how exactly I can do that i form of coding?

Comment: One more question I am uploading pictures to ACS from android app. I got no error in my code but photos are not uploading.

Comment: Appcelerator Cloud services (Services provided by appcelerator to upload data to server)

Comment: @Nadeem Sorry I'm not familiar with ACS. If you're having a different problem you should probably post another question.

Comment: @Nadeem I believe my solution answered your question. If so please accept the answer. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create activity in android with

```
<activity
            android:name=".youractivityname"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

And add list view in this activity with your desired item in the list.
The theme dialog creates your activity as a dialog and show as its a kind of popup 
Please let me know if this helps you

Comment: consider only distance bar at the top of screen and when i click on that bar a list should be open a like a popmenu. not the list below that bar . how would i do that??